# Can I use 3.5 expansions for pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, new-players, tome-of-battle

Can I use 3.5 expansion books for pathfinder?? I want to because I want to use different things I read in 3.5 expanisions. Also tell me in your answer which are compatible and which aren't. I'm reading up on pathfinder a bit and am curious of how it would play out.

I haven't gotten to play either yet and wanted an outside opinion.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, definitely.  Pathfinder is based off the 3.5 SRD, with some minor fixes and customizations. Almost anything published for D&D 3.x should work with little to no modification necessary.

As for a list of what is/isn't compatible, there was a LOT of material published for 3.x so that's a rather time consuming request.

Comment: Sorry For asking about a list. I just was paranoid of bringing in a guide and suddenly the fabric of the game's ruleset tears to ribbons. Thank you for your answer though Since it helps me a lot.